# Не могу установить Homebrew MacOS

Tags: macos, консоль, mac, homebrew

Итак, нужно установить HomeBrew, но при запуске скрипта с официального сайта он пытается установить Command Line Tools, которые у меня уже есть в составе Xcode, выдает окно с надписью: "Не удается установить ПО, так как обновление недоступно через сервер Обновления ПО", после нажатия OK установка прерывается с ошибкой:

```
    xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory' /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
    Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Как это решить?

Comment: Xcode установили? Лицензионно соглашение приняли? `xcode-select --install`?

Comment: @НикитаУмнов > которые у меня уже есть в составе Xcode

Comment: @НикитаУмнов $ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
Да и тулсы эти у меня есть и работают

Comment: Посмотри этот вариант https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error

Comment: @НикитаУмнов Увы, нет, что бы я не пробовал с этой страницы, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел, возможно, решение тут. https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/1726.

```
while ! ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" 
</dev/null; do
    sleep 5
    echo 'retrying homebrew install...'
done
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло!